# jQuery - find last class on the element

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

How to find last class on the element without knowing exact number of classes?

Our element:

```
 <div class="class-1 class-2 some-other-class"></div>
```

Normal approach with split will not work here, as we do not know the number of classes. Can we check the length of the `.split(' ')` ?

```
var i = $('div').prop('class');
var j = i.split(' ')[x];
```

Any suggestions much appreciated.

Comment: If you want to do in one line then `i.split(' ')[i.split(' ').length - 1]` will get you the last class.

Comment: Classes are essentially unordered entities. Personally, I wouldn't want to rely on javascript/jQuery delivering the "correct" result. If I needed to know the last class added to an element (or a set of elements) then I would keep track of it by other means.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

The simplest solution is to use `pop`, which accesses the last element in the array.

```
var lastClass = $('div').attr('class').split(' ').pop();
```

Note that `pop` also removes the element from the array, but since you aren't doing anything else with it, that's not a problem.

Answer (score 18):

```
var classStr = $('div').attr('class'),
    lastClass = classStr.substr( classStr.lastIndexOf(' ') + 1);
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/QStkd/526/)**

As `classStr` contains class names separated by a single `space`, so `lastIndexOf(' ')` will find the last `space` and make partition from there and give you the last `class` name.