# Remove last class

Tags: jquery, css, removeclass

When clicking on a div I want to remove the last of it's classes (which is always the third). So, when clicking on the div below I want class3 to be removed, which can have different class names (but always ends with '_hover').

Is there an easy way of doing this?

```
<div id="container" class="class1 class2 class3">

$('#container').on('click', function() {
    $(this).removeClass(?);
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

One simple way would be to find the last class, then remove it:

```
var lastClass = $('#container').attr('class').split(' ').pop();
$(this).removeClass(lastClass);
```

In vanilla `JavaScript`, you can use:

```js
class.classList.add('className');

// or
 
class.classList.remove('className');
```

Comment: or better  `$(this).removeClass(this.className.split(' ').pop());`

Comment: I did that to separate the steps.

Comment: Finding last class of an element: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11258346/jquery-find-last-class-on-the-element

Comment: I know, note `className` dont have to use jquery always... :)