# How to find the closest li that has the class 'active'

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I am trying to generate some jQuery that will find the closest list item that has the class attribute and insert some html directly after it?

I've got the following but this needs work.. its called from an on click event()

```
$('.controls').on('click.add', function()
{               
       $(this).parent().closest('li.active').insertAfter('<p>HTML</p>');
});
```

Can anyone assist - in this instance i'd want to select the 3rd li (based upon the class the last 'active' list item) - and insert some simple HTML after it.

```
<ul class="controls">
  <li class="active"></li>
  <li class="active"></li>
  <li class="active"></li>
  <li class="inactive"></li>
  <li class="inactive"></li>
</ul>
<a href="#" class="add"> Add Prize</a>
```

Comment: what is `this` referring to

Comment: $this is referring to the click event()

Comment: in this case which li do you want? the first one?

Comment: I'm trying to get the 3rd list item (the last list item with the class 'active');

Comment: Where is `.add` button? Inside of what?

Comment: Should we assume that your real list has valid HTML (the li elements are closed) and that you want the "simple HTML" within that last list item?

Comment: @j08691 By the way, ommiting closing `li` is perfectly valid.

Comment: good call - i have closed the li tags

Comment: And the HTML you want to insert, it belongs within the last active list item correct? Not after it.

Comment: You would not want to have `p` inside `ul` . It's not valid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try doing it like this:

```
$('.add').on('click', function()
{
     $(this).prev().find('li.active:last').after('<p>HTML</p>');

});
```

Comment: This produces invalid HTML. You can't have anything other than a `<li>` as a child of a `<ul>`.

Answer (score 2):

"The simplest solution is to use pop, which accesses the last element in the array.

```
var lastClass = $('div').attr('class').split(' ').pop();
```

Note that pop also removes the element from the array, but since you aren't doing anything else with it, that's not a problem."

stolen from: [jQuery - find last class on the element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11258346/jquery-find-last-class-on-the-element)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var $controls = $('.controls');
$('.add').on('click', function() {               
    $controls.find('li.active:last').after('<li>HTML</li>');
});
```

Also note, that you probably want `.after` rather than `.insertAfter`. Plus as pointed in comments you should not insert `p` as a child of `ul`, so I changed it to `li`.

Comment: This produces invalid HTML. You can't have anything other than a `<li>` as a child of a `<ul>`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".controls li.active").last().after('<p>HTML</p>');
```

Comment: This produces invalid HTML. You can't have anything other than a `<li>` as a child of a `<ul>`.