# how to get the last class of a div

Tags: javascript, jquery

in the example below the last class of a div is `tex1` and I need it in console
something like this:

```js
let last = $('#tex').attr('class').last();
console.log(last);  // error
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='tex' class='tex texonly tex1'>lorem</div>
```

Comment: [`.attr()`](https://api.jquery.com/attr): _"Note: **Attribute values are strings** with the exception of a few attributes such as value and tabindex."_

Comment: Does this answer your question? [jQuery - find last class on the element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11258346/jquery-find-last-class-on-the-element)

Comment: What's your use-case for this?   Class order should not matter, so `class='tex1 tex'` should be the same as `class='tex tex1'` - if the order is important, then there's something wrong - so likely an XY Problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `.split` and `.pop()` to get the last class from your element.

`.last()` is used for doing something on the last element in the your parent div or etc

Run snippet below to see it working.

```js
let last = $('#tex').attr('class').split(' ').pop();
console.log(last); // error
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div id='tex' class='tex texonly tex1'>lorem</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

"The simplest solution is to use pop, which accesses the last element in the array.

```
var lastClass = $('#tex').attr('class').split(' ').pop();
```

Note that pop also removes the element from the array, but since you aren't doing anything else with it, that's not a problem."

This answer was provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11258346/jquery-find-last-class-on-the-element) for a similar question.

Comment: _"The simplest solution is to use pop, which accesses the last element in the array."_ - There's no array, unless you convert the string returned by `.attr()` into an array by splitting it - what is exactly what you're doing. Then say so...

Comment: Also, kudos for including a link to your source - when you have enough rep, you'll be able to vote-close questions as duplicates (which I've done for you, it needs others/OP to confirm).

Comment: just copied solution of `AlwaysHelping`

Comment: Yes, and I put the link where the solution was initially provided. I don't get it what I did wrong, it is not like I claim that I've discover it. That it is why I put the quotes.

Answer (score 0):

With vanilla JS you could use [`classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) and get the last class by `length`.

```js
const classes = document.getElementById("tex").classList;
console.log(classes[classes.length-1]);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='tex' class='tex texonly tex1'>lorem</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript's `.classList` to get an array-like list (then convert to a "real" array).  A polyfill will give you `array.last()`.

```js
if (!Array.prototype.last){
    Array.prototype.last = function(){
        return this[this.length - 1];
    };
};

let last = [...$('#tex')[0].classList].last();
console.log(last);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='tex' class='tex texonly tex1'>lorem</div>
```

Comment: Messing with the prototype of `Array` just so that there's a `.last()` method (`.pop()`)? Which is only relevant after converting the `DOMTokenList` into an actual array? `const listOfClasses = document.querySelector("#text").classList; console.log(listOfClasses[listOfClasses.length -1]`

Comment: @Andreas OP asked how to get it *using `.last()`*